# Unknown servertag ScriptManager AJAX in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

Im trying to implement a 'numericupdown' AJAX control within the gridview cell of my ASP.NET website.

I have dragged and dropped a 'scriptManager' from the AJAX Extentions part of the toolbox.

Currently when i run my website (which is hosted locally) i am getting the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'ScriptManager1:numericupdownextender'.

Source Error: 


Line 85:         </asp:GridView>
Line 86: 
Line 87:         <ScriptManager1:numericupdownextender 
Line 88:         id="NumericUpDownExtender1" 
Line 89:         runat="server"
```

I have done some research and it seems this is a common issue but having never dealt with AJAX before Im stuck with how to solve it. Here is the server side code of my website:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ViewCDs._Default" %>

 <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
```

### Welcome to 'CD Collection'. From here you can browse and search for all of your favourite music!

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Search Type:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>CD Title</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Artist</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Music Genre</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Search Term:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cdsCollectionsConnectionString3 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [cds]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="918px" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="_id" AllowPaging="True" 
        PageSize="1">
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign = "Center" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="_id" HeaderText="_id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="_id" Visible="false" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Pic">

            <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Image ID = "Image1" ImageUrl='<%# (string) FormatImageUrl( (string) Eval("pic")) %>' runat="server" />

            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="185px" />


            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cdTitle" HeaderText="CD Title" 
                SortExpression="cdTitle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="artist" HeaderText="Artist" 
                SortExpression="artist" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="genre" HeaderText="Music Genre" SortExpression="genre" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="pic" HeaderText="pic" SortExpression="pic" Visible="false" />



              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Picc">
              <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuan" Text = "1" Height="15" runat="server" />


              <asp:ImageButton 
                ID="ImageButton2" 
                runat="server" 
                ImageUrl="Images/arrowup.jpg" 
                AlternateText="Up"
                    Width="15" 
                    Height="15" />

                 <asp:ImageButton 
                ID="ImageButton1" 
                runat="server" 
                ImageUrl="Images/arrowdown.jpg" 
                AlternateText="Up"
                    Width="15" 
                    Height="15" />

            </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>




        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <ScriptManager1:numericupdownextender 
    id="NumericUpDownExtender1" 
    runat="server" 
    targetcontrolid="TxtQuan"
        width="120" 
        refvalues="" 
        servicedownmethod="" 
        serviceupmethod="" 
        targetbuttondownid=""
        targetbuttonupid="" 
        minimum="1" 
        maximum="10" />


</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else getting this error message. Please ensure you download the AJAX toolkit from the ASP AJAX site. Then drag the ToolKitScriptManager onto your page.